# Why doesn't my span class work during animation?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create an animation with a text that rotates when changing words. Everything works, but if I add the class to the span inside my css the animation no longer works.
This is the HTML code:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.words-rotate {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

span .words-rotate
/* Here, if I only use span, everything works. If I add the '.words-rotate' class, it no longer works.   */

{
  animation: animate 10s ease infinite;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    top: 0
  }
  20% {
    top: 0
  }
  25% {
    top: -34px
  }
  45% {
    top: -34px
  }
  50% {
    top: -69px
  }
  70% {
    top: -69px
  }
  75% {
    top: -105px
  }
  95% {
    top: -105px
  }
  100% {
    top: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="home-text">
      I am,
      <span class="words-rotate">
            dreamer <br>
            traveller <br>
            creative <br>
            scuba diver
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks to those who will respond!

Comment: I think things are slightly the wrong way round. You want a fixed element with a certain height and overflow hidden and within that you want to move the text up so that only one line shows at a time. Also it's quite tricky getting text aligned using lineheight etc you may like to consider putting each line into its own element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `span` has class `.words-rotate`, not `span` has child with class `.words-rotate`. Remove space between selectors: `span.words-rotate`

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.words-rotate {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

span.words-rotate {
  animation: animate 10s ease infinite;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    top: 0
  }
  20% {
    top: 0
  }
  25% {
    top: -34px
  }
  45% {
    top: -34px
  }
  50% {
    top: -69px
  }
  70% {
    top: -69px
  }
  75% {
    top: -105px
  }
  95% {
    top: -105px
  }
  100% {
    top: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="home-text">
      I am,
      <span class="words-rotate">
            dreamer <br>
            traveller <br>
            creative <br>
            scuba diver
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but if I remove the space. Animation works the other way round, if I remove the class it works the right way round. Could there be some other error?

Comment: @GiorgiaLari well, you change position from `absolute` into `relative`. Maybe that's why?